# htaccess replace character in query and redirect

Tags: regex, .htaccess, redirect

I need to replace '_' to '+' in query string than redirect:

`site.com/abc_def/`

to

`site.com/search.php?q=abc+def`

I tried this

```
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/((.*)\_(.*))?$ /search.php?q=$1+$2 [R=301,L]
```

Comment: `RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/((.*)\_(.*))?$ /search.php?q=$1+$2 [R=301,L]`

Comment: what happened when you tried that?

Comment: /abc -> /search.php?q=abc+, /abc_def -> /search.php?q=abc_def+

Comment: Why do you have `([^/]+)` at the start? Provide more details of example input URLs and expected rewritten URLs.

Comment: Input: site.com/abc_def/. Rewritten: site.com/search.php?q=abc+def

Comment: `([^/]+)` - it was written by admin, it can be replaced with a regexp for random character

Answer (score 2, accepted):

These are 2 rules that should work for you:

```
RewriteEngine On

# first replace _ by + recursively
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^([^_]*)_(.*)$ /$1+$2 [L]

# once all _s are gone, rewrite to /search.php?q=<search>
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^([^_]+)$ /search.php?q=$1 [L,QSA]
```

Comment: server returns Internal Server Error when I try 'site.com/abc/' or 'site.com/abc_def/'

Comment: This is properly tested code. Read the error.log and update here what error do you see there.