# Rewrite string as path separator in Apache rewrite rule

Tags: apache, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting, path-separator

I'm working with a third party site which caches the wave file by name, not by url. I have lot of wave files in my system with the same name but in different directories, but the third-party site plays the wrong file when requesting for a file with same name but in different directory.

So, I thought of removing the slash ('/') from url and combine it with the string **_dir_separator_** to make the wave file unique across the system.

How can I rewrite the url so all occurrences of _dir_separator_ internally rewrite to slash?

For eg., requesting for this file `http://mysite/media_dir_separator_voice_scripts_dir_separator_script_en_v11.wav`

should pick this one `http://mysite/media/voice_scripts/script_en.wav`

Please note directory structure is of multiple level deep so rewriting fixed number of pattern would not work.

Edit: I changed my mind and wish to use hyphen(-) instead of _dir_sepator_ string. Importantly, I need this to work without rewrite.

```
   RewriteRule ^([^-]*)-([^-]*-.*) $1/$2 [N]
    RewriteRule ^([^-]*)-([^-]*)$ $1/$2 [L]
```

Answer (score 0):

If the host has enabled mod-rewrite, and has set the `AllowOverride` to provide you with the ability to set htaccess files, you can use the following:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} _dir_separator_ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)_dir_separator_(.+)$ /$1/$2 [R,L]
```

Testing it with curl on my system gives:

```
$ curl -LI http://localhost/media_dir_separator_voice_scripts_dir_separator_script_en_v11.wav

HTTP/1.1 302 Found
Date: Sun, 11 Sep 2016 05:59:26 GMT
Server: Apache/2.4.18 (Win64) PHP/7.0.4
Location: http://localhost/media_dir_separator_voice_scripts/script_en_v11.wav
Content-Type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1

HTTP/1.1 302 Found
Date: Sun, 11 Sep 2016 05:59:26 GMT
Server: Apache/2.4.18 (Win64) PHP/7.0.4
Location: http://localhost/media/voice_scripts/script_en_v11.wav
Content-Type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1

HTTP/1.1 404 Not Found
Date: Sun, 11 Sep 2016 05:59:26 GMT
Server: Apache/2.4.18 (Win64) PHP/7.0.4
Content-Type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1
```

---

For usage with the hyphen (`-`) character:

```
RewriteRule ^(.*)-(.+)$ /$1/$2 [N]
```

Comment: I changed my mind. Instead of _dir_separate_, I prefer to go with simple dash (-). I will sure that none of files have dash in them. I tried this

       RewriteRule ^([^-]*)-([^-]*-.*) $1/$2 [N]
        RewriteRule ^([^-]*)-([^-]*)$ $1/$2 [L]

But, it doesn't seem to work. I need the rewrite solution to work without redirect.

Comment: @SenG Don't put the `L` flag.

Comment: I used your exact snippet in my vhost file, it still redirects. I can see the new URL in the browser.

Comment: Shall we derive the solution from this answer?

http://stackoverflow.com/a/19341312/959939

Comment: @SenG In my code example above, replace `[R,L]` with `[N]`

Comment: Not working. 403 - Permission denied. I enabled rewrite log and here it is.

applying pattern '^([^-]*)-([^-]*-.*)' to uri '/media-voice_scripts-appt_confirmed_en.wav'
rewrite '/media-voice_scripts-appt_confirmed_en.wav' -> '/media/voice_scripts-appt_confirmed_en.wav'
applying pattern '^([^-]*)-([^-]*-.*)' to uri '/media/voice_scripts-appt_confirmed_en.wav'
applying pattern '^([^-]*)-([^-]*)$' to uri '/media/voice_scripts-appt_confirmed_en.wav'
rewrite '/media/voice_scripts-appt_confirmed_en.wav' -> '/media/voice_scripts/